How to solve $6x^3-18x^2+9x-1 = 0$?
I am trying to learn the basics of cubic equations. Will be happy for help or guidance. As suggested, I will elaborate on my attempt:
Placing $y=\frac{x+3}{3}$, gives:
\begin{align}
\frac{y^3}{27} - \frac{y}{2} - \frac{2}{3} = 0
\end{align}
The coefficient of the linear term is negative so we can not use the trigonometric solution in the provided link.
There is another substitution $z=x-1$ which leads to
\begin{align}
z^3 - \frac{3z}{2} - \frac{2}{3} = 0.
\end{align}
Also here, the substitution $z=u+u^{-1}$ does not help.

This might help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371108/what-are-the-ways-to-solve-cubic-equations

Look up the rational root theorem, it's a good place to start.

This question is similar to: Is there anything like “cubic formula”?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you want to find exact values of $x$ satisfying equation, it might be sweaty. But at least derivative tells us that it has $3$ distinct roots

This question is similar to: How to solve $8t^3-4t^2-4t+1=0$. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The first 2 terms are six times the first two terms of $(x-1)^3$. Then fset u=x-1. This transforms the equation into a depressed cubic by getting rid of the quadratic term. Then set u=v+p/v. Should get an expression you can express as a quadratic. This is one way of deriving the cubic formula.

I do not see how the trigonometric tricks used there can help here - Read again this post. Your cubic has three real roots. The answers in the post explains it : When a cubic equation has $3$ real roots, one uses a trigonometric substitution!

Your attempt is false. Setting $x=3(y-1)$ cannot depress the cubic. Better follow the advice above and set $x=y+1$.

Is there a unique substitution? it seems that both work

Any rescaling doesn't bring back a quadratic term. So, you can set $x=ky+1$ for any $k\ne0$. The simplest is $k=1$. Please delete your first (wrong) attempt with $y=\frac{x+3}{3}$.

Will the further substitution $z = u+u^{-1}$ can help here? i do not see it

@AnneBauval I cannot edit it

Yes you can, you already did several times. Click on "Edit". As for $z=u+u^{-1}$, it won't help here. Apply any method of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation Anyway, your three roots won't look nice. Did you choose that equation at random?

@AnneBauval Not random at all, it comes from a very nice problem in online optimization. What I actually need is a particular root of this eq. and not all of them
