# Resolving cubic equation where domain is complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I unable to resolve the following equation (I don't have any idea how even start resolving this equation):
$$8z^3-12z^2+6z-1-i=0$$

Comment: $(8)z^3-(12)z^2+(6)z+(-1-i)z^0=0$.  This is just a cubic.  Solve it like you would any other cubic.  The only challenge is to recognize and keep track of that you might need both the real and imaginary components written together for each of the coefficients and that here the $-1$ and the $-i$ were both parts of the constant part of the polynomial.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You will have heard of the "quadratic formula"... you know, the $\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ thing?  Well, there's a version for cubics and quartics as well.  (*No, there is not one for quintics or higher*).  Now... granted... not that many people bother learning or memorizing [the cubic formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html), it is long and tedious (*the quartic is even worse*), and just knowing it exists at all is more than enough most of the time.  The fact you are talking about complex numbers is irrelevant.  It is the same formula.

Comment: There is one very simple root

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there anything like “cubic formula”?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052616/is-there-anything-like-cubic-formula)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I would not expect any of these roots to be spotted by inspection by a beginner.  Which root are you suggesting is so "simple"?  $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}$?  If you could spot that, then you are quite impressive at this... but I for one struggle trying to evaluate the polynomial with that value in my head quickly, much less plucking that out of thin air ahead of time.

Comment: @JMoravitz. This is the "advantage" of being blind. I memorize almost everything (not the quartic). Cheers :-)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici : Waouh ! $\frac12(1-i)$ is not what is called a "very simple root", even in France, n'est-ce pas ? :) :)

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen. In Pau, it is ! Back to serious, since $\pm i$ is not a root, neither $\pm 1\pm i$, what do you want to try ? Cheers and nice to meet you.

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen  You might try the rational root theorem in the Gaussian integers.  It suggests Claude's root as a possible answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $w=2z$. Then your equation is

$$w^3-3w^2+3w-1 = i.$$

So

$$(w-1)^3 = i.$$

So $w-1$ is a cube root of $i$. So the three roots are $z=(t+1)/2$ where $t$ is a cube root of $i$.

Comment: Thank You, it is really beautiful solution!

Answer (score 1):

So, $C:=\frac12(1-i)$ is a very very simple root.
Then,
$$8z^3-12z^2+6z-1-i=0$$

$$\iff$$

$$(z-C)(4z^2-2(i+2)z+i)=0$$